# Windows Application has stopped working :: Event Name CLR20r3

Tags: .net, vb.net, invalidoperationexception

I developed an applicatin using Visual Studio.Net 2008  Team System with Infragistics Net Advantage Tools 2010.3 and made a Setup Exe file for my application and installed on client machines where they have both Windows7 32 bit and WindowsXP Service Pack 2. ( I have also tried both way by Setup Property TargetPlatform x86 and x64)

But when i install and run this application (exe) file in development machine its installed and run correctly. Only on Client's machine its installed correctly but not running, giving the error when double clicking on the exe file.

[image]

The Complete Error is following:

Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: al-deihani.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4dac0949
  Problem Signature 04: Al-Deihani
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4dac0949
  Problem Signature 07: 47
  Problem Signature 08: c6
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: It's telling you that an `InvalidOperationException` has occurred. You need to figure out the *cause* of that exception. You need to post a full stack trace if you want our help debugging it.

Comment: I fixed this problem with this solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133879/application-crashes-on-startup-missing-microsoft-visualbasic-powerpacks][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133879/application-crashes-on-startup-missing-microsoft-visualbasic-powerpacks

Answer (score 4):

This is just because the application is built in non unicode language fonts and you are running the system on unicode fonts. change your default non unicode fonts to arabic by going in regional settings advanced tab in control panel. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the client computer has the same or higher version of the .NET framework that you built your program to.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your comments and suggestions...........finally i found the error after 10 days headache........it was causing due to SQLDMO.Dll............I solved this by installing theMicrosoft SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components on client's machine and application start working fine..........Can be downloaded from the following link

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6c3e9ef-ba29-4a43-8d69-a2bed18fe73c

Comment: @Malik Please ad that as it's own answer and accept *that* answer.  Leaving it as a comment does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Some times this problem arise when Application is build in one PC and try to run another PC.
And also build the application with Visual Studio 2010.I have the following problem

```
Problem Description
    Stop Working
Problem Signature
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: diagnosticcentermngr.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4f8c1772
  Problem Signature 04: System.Drawing
  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4a275e83
  Problem Signature 07: 7af
  Problem Signature 08: 6c
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Dont worry, Please check out following link and install .net framework 4.Although my application .net properties was .net framework 2.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718

restart your PC and try again.

Comment: If this Procedure did't work then go to Control panel, Select user account go to User Access Control and select the bar at never notify. Now go to your exe directory, right click on it and select "Run as Administrator" . Hope that will work.(Md Riad Hossain)

Answer (score 0):

Download and install SAP Crystal Reports Runtime engine for .net (32 bit or 64 bit) depending on your os version. Should work there after