# Could not load Microsoft.visualBasic.PowerPAcks (even though dll is next to exe)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, powerpacks, powerpack

I've developped an application on VS2010, in Vb.net. 
All is working well on some computers, but some are throwing this error :

Could not load Microsoft.visualBasic.PowerPacks.

I've already encounter this eror, and copying the Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll next to my .exe fixed the problem. 
Still, some users can't use the application, despite the dll next to the exe.

Any ideas ?

Ps: I'm in a AD domain, and i'm not one of the administrators, so no installation possible whatsoever. The framework 4.0 is all I got installed.

Comment: Have you tried referencing the dll from the app folder before compiling?

Comment: And how can I do that ?
The application path may change with time, how can I reference a dll with a dynamic 'NextToMe' Path ?

Comment: if it's in the same folder as the app, say the Release folder, when you add it as a reference it should look for the dll in the the same folder as the app when you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted all from \bin 
Went through a full recompilation.

It's now working. 
I don't know why.

But it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I think your case (which was my case too) is connected with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17133879/505893), which has a good accepted solution.