# vb.net application runs on only vs2010 installed machines

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I hae created a simple application with visual studio 2010 and I got the .exe file from release directory after building.

It runs on my machines. Also only on the machines that VS2010 installed machines. This exception occurs on other machines. How can I get resolved this problem.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Game 
CEA.exe
Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  

The error is: Could not load file or assembly
 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution by @Hans Passant:

> Click the "Show All Files" icon on the
>   toolbar in the Solution Explorer window. That now shows the References
>   node. Expand it and select the PowerPacks reference. In the Properties
>   window, change the Copy Local property to True.
>
> Rebuild and your build directory now will have a copy of the DLL. Copy
>   it along with the EXE onto the target machine.

Taken from here: [Application crashes on startup - missing Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133879/application-crashes-on-startup)

Comment: Didn't work. But something changed. It does not show anything.