# VB.net application stops working on different PC

Tags: vb.net, crash-reports

I have a VB.net stand alone application which has all the requisites and dlls for it in one folder, but my problem is it crashes and stops working on my other Computer that does not have visual studio but has .net framework 4.5 installed. What seems to be causing this? 
This is my first time in making a stand alone application, I am really confused right now.

Here is the error after it crashes:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: TestApp.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 522f1be8
  Problem Signature 04: Test App
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 522f1be8
  Problem Signature 07: 81
  Problem Signature 08: aa
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: Does your app try to modify filesystem? Imean if try to create file or something like this?

Comment: See if this applies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701767/windows-application-has-stopped-working-problem-event-name-clr20r3

Comment: My form_load is empty. i did not placed codes there. It is able to load the splash screen i have created though but after that it stops working and crashes.

Comment: Is there any software i need to install aside from .net 4.5 to make this function? please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: Are you using outside GUI controllers? and if so have you added them correctly? also try and "remove unused references", this did it for me a few times.

Comment: i am using all my references. what do you mean by outside GUI controllers?

Comment: i missed one reference which was VisualBasicPowerPacks. now my App runs smoothly. damn having lack of sleep sure does have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to include the reference named VisualBasicPowerPacks and now my App runs.