# VB.net Error on some machines

Tags: .net, vb.net, runtime-error

I am creating a vb.net application for internal use but, when I move the .exe off the development machine, I get nothing but errors. One example of the errors is below. I'm not certain what the problem is, but the program is written and assembled for .net 3.5 and the target CPU architecture is x86 which should work fine on anywhere as long as it has .net 3.5 or newer, correct?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701767/windows-application-has-stopped-working-event-name-clr20r3) question, but all of the involved machines already haved the crystal reports runtime (though I'm not doing anything with crystal in my program), all have .net framework 4.0 which is enough to cover 3.5, and I'm not doing anything with fancy fonts or languages other than english. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10) which seems to say that the error was of type `System.net.Sockets.Socket` Thoughts?

Below is the image of the error that shows and below that is the text in the "View Problem Details"  section. Any tips on this error? Development machine is Win 7 32bit, and the servers are Windows 2008 R2, 64 bit.

[image: Error]

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: joblocationchanges.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 535e814c
  Problem Signature 04: System
  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 506c18e6
  Problem Signature 07: 2855
  Problem Signature 08: 21
  Problem Signature 09: System.Net.Sockets.Socket
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.18.10
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

below here is first the message and then the stracktrace of the error

```
"An invalid argument was supplied"
   at System.Net.SafeCloseSocketAndEvent.CreateWSASocketWithEvent(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, Boolean autoReset, Boolean signaled)
     at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.AddressChangeListener.StartHelper(NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler caller, Boolean captureContext, StartIPOptions startIPOptions)
     at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.add_NetworkAddressChanged(NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler value)
     at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.add_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(NetworkAvailableEventHandler handler)
     at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs eventArgs)
     at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()"
```

Comment: You have an unhandled exception. Debugging at this point is excruciating. If you add an exception handler that at least logs a stacktrace you'll be in a much better position.

Comment: There should be an error in Event Viewer. What does it say?

Comment: PLaying around with it some more, I've just found that on my dev PC it runs fine through VS but when I copy out the compiled .exe it no longer runs on dev machine. Nunzabar I'm checking out the Event log

Comment: If you can reproduce the exception on your dev machine, you can attach a debugger when the application crashes. From the error message you provided I can see that the exception is thrown [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_SafeNetHandles.cs#2557).

Comment: Thanks Dominic. I changed it to catch unhandled exceptions and was able to attach a debugger and get the value of the .Message and .StackTrace Properties. I added them above.

Comment: Try to log the parameters right before the function is called. Maybe a setting is different (ex: hard coded setting file path and can't find it anymore). Are it might be that you have to run the application as administrator.

Comment: @the_lotus running as Admin has no effect.

Comment: further refinement to running on the dev machine. Running the file from network storage fails and throws errors. running from a local drive like C: then it runs entirely fine

Comment: Typical signs of anti-malware messing with you.

Comment: Anti malware might be blocking it? God I hate those

Comment: I think that was it Hans! I have no confirmation of it- but moving the program to a directory where we keep programs on the network and running from there works fine on all machines

Comment: @HansPassant checked with the person in charge of our AV and it had protections for .exe's running from the network to access the network. But the one folder was whitelisted. You're right. If you'll toss it in as a proper answer I'll mark you