# VB.NET application stops responding

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I developed a program in `VB.NET 2010` (`.NET version 4`). It runs in my laptop perfectly. I installed it to client's computer (`Windows 7`). While I run the application in client's computer, it stops responding.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701767/windows-application-has-stopped-working-event-name-clr20r3) and repair `.NET 4` but the problem persists by giving the below error message.

```
Description:
 Stopped working

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\WER46BF.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\WER7030.tmp.mdmp

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

What should I do ?

**UPDATE:**

I found something (not the solution). I am using a `Sub procedure` that loads the `crystal report engine` while the application starts. I block the `procedure` and the application runs. But while I generates a report (`Crystal Report`), it again stops working.

I am using `Crystal Report 13_0_14`.

What would be the solution ?

Comment: Does it consistently stop working? Does it ever start working? Does it stop at a particular action or event?

Comment: @Mort Hi, thanks for your response. Yes it consistently stop working. It is not working in that computer. The computer is ok. I have tested my application in another computer. It works great there, but not in this computer.

Comment: What's the nature of the application? VB.Net can be used to create console applications, web applications, at least two different types of desktop applications, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever **Windows form application**.

Comment: Have you looked at the memory dump file WER7030.tmp.mdmp? It might provide more details.

Comment: Could you put a simple app on the workstation to see if it is an issue with your app or an underlying problem?

Comment: **Please see my update**